# Gmaps4rails: adjustMapToBounds after changing the map size

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, gmaps4rails

I would like to readjust the map after resizing the map container. I did the following, but it does not work. What am I missing?

```
Gmaps.map.callback = function() {
    var g4map = Gmaps.map,
    map = g4map.map;

    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function(){
        $("#map").animate({height: 300});
        g4map.adjustMapToBounds();
    });
};
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer to my question... I had to trigger the resize event on the map to update the bounds.

```
Gmaps.map.callback = function() {
    var g4map = Gmaps.map,
    map = g4map.map;

    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function(){
        $("#map").animate({height: 300}, function() {
            google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
            g4map.adjustMapToBounds();
        });
    });
};
```